Data on the number of connections in Firebird is not displayed correctly
On the project there are many databases in the form of files for Firebird. I need to know the number of connections to the database.
There are about 100 databases and I would like to have statistics on the total number of connections.
Here is the code I am using.
if (($service = ibase_service_attach('127.0.0.1/3050', 'sysdba', 'masterkey')) != FALSE) {
    // Successfully attached.

    // Output the info
    echo "Server version: " . ibase_server_info($service, IBASE_SVC_SERVER_VERSION) . "\n";
    echo "Server implementation: " . ibase_server_info($service, IBASE_SVC_IMPLEMENTATION) . "\n";
    echo "Server users: " . print_r(ibase_server_info($service, IBASE_SVC_GET_USERS), true) . "\n";
    echo "Server directory: " . ibase_server_info($service, IBASE_SVC_GET_ENV) . "\n";
    echo "Server lock path: " . ibase_server_info($service, IBASE_SVC_GET_ENV_LOCK) . "\n";
    echo "Server lib path: " . ibase_server_info($service, IBASE_SVC_GET_ENV_MSG) . "\n";
    echo "Path of user db: " . ibase_server_info($service, IBASE_SVC_USER_DBPATH) . "\n";
    echo "Established connections: " . print_r(ibase_server_info($service, IBASE_SVC_SVR_DB_INFO),true) . "\n";

    // Detach from server (disconnect)
    ibase_service_detach($service);

}
else {
    // Output message on error
    $conn_error = ibase_errmsg();
    die($conn_error);
}

I get as a result:

ibase_server_info($service, IBASE_SVC_SVR_DB_INFO) Established connections attachments always returns 0
What if I want to go into a database and I run a query
SELECT MON$ATTACHMENT_ID, MON$USER, MON$REMOTE_ADDRESS
FROM MON$ATTACHMENTS;

I get as a result:


It looks like you have two Firebird instances running.

What is the ServerMode configured in firebird.conf?

You most likely are using Firebird in Classic server mode (setting ServerMode = Classic or ServerMode = MultiProcess in firebird.conf). In Classic server mode, each database and service attachment has its own process.
The information request item info_svr_db_info (IBASE_SVC_SVR_DB_INFO in case of the Firebird PHP driver) only enumerates the database attachments and databases of the attached server process. And as a service connection in Classic mode has its own process, that process has no database attachments, and thus reports 0 for the number of attachments and the number of databases.
The virtual table MON$ATTACHMENTS does more work, and enumerates all connections to the current database (but is not aware of attachments to other databases!).
So, if you want to use info_svr_db_info, you will need to set ServerMode to Super (a.k.a. ThreadedDedicated) or SuperClassic (a.k.a. ThreadedShared) mode. However, as Super is the default in a new installation, I assume there was a specific reason Classic mode was chosen, so don't just change this setting without considering the reasons why you chose Classic to begin with.
Alternatively, as user13964273 mentioned in the comments, you might be connecting to a different Firebird installation.
